# Adding or removing CSS class onClick

Tags: html, css, responsive

so I've currently got it setup so that when a panel is clicked (active:green) and then once clicked away going back to black - however when the panel has been clicked I want to replace the `arrow-down` class with the `arrow-up` class. I've tried adding `tab.classList.add('arrow-up')` just how the green background is being added but it flips the entire div. i've got a working JS Fiddle however you won't be able to view the icons sadly - any ideas/ help would be really appreciated!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/simoncunningham/a3e6514r/19/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h2>Expanding Grid</h2>
      <p>Click on the boxes below:</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b1');">
        <img src="./Icons/Banking.svg" />
        <p>Banking</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onClick="openTab('b2');">
        <img src="./Icons/Regtech.svg" />
        <p>RegTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onClick="openTab('b3');">
        <img src="./Icons/InsurTech.svg" />
        <p>InsurTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onClick="openTab('b4');">
        <img src="./Icons/Lending.svg" />
        <p>Lending</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Full-width columns: (hidden by default) -->
    <div id="b1" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h3>Banking</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b2" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>RegTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b3" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>InsurTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b4" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Lending</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- Bottom four columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b5');">
        <img src="./Icons/Accounting.svg" />
        <p>Accounting</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b6');">
        <img src="./Icons/Payments.svg" />
        <p>Payments</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b7');">
        <img src="./Icons/Quote.svg" />
        <p>Quote Aggregators</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="column" onclick="openTab('b8');">
        <img src="./Icons/WealthTech.svg" />
        <p>WealthTech</p>
        <img class="arrow-down" src="./Icons/arrow-down.png" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="b5" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Accounting</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b6" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Payments</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b7" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>Quote</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="b8" class="containerTab" style="display: none; background: black">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn"
        >&times;</span
      >
      <h2>WealthTech</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, te quo doctus abhorreant, et pri deleniti
        intellegat, te sanctus inermis ullamcorper nam. Ius error diceret
        deseruisse ad
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
    function openTab(tabName) {
      var i, x;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName('containerTab');
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = 'block';
    }

    // Get all the tabs into a collection
    // (don't use .getElementsByClassName()!)
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.column');

    // Set up a click event handler on each of the tabs
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      tab.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        // Loop over all the tabs and remove the active class
        tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
          tab.classList.remove('active-column');
        });

        // Set the background of the clicked tab
        this.classList.add('active-column');
      });
    });
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
.active-column {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 226px;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.containerTab {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Closable button inside the container tab */
.closebtn {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.arrow-up {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing where you are adding the arrow-up and arrow-down classes? It's probably an issue of not applying the class to the tabs child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you might be adding the `arrow-up` class to `tab` element. But you meant to add it to the `img` element which is the 3rd child of `tab` (assuming 3rd child since it has default class of `arrow-down`).

So following is probably what you need :-

`tab.children[2].classList.add('arrow-up');`

Comment: thanks - that's really helpful! appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    // Loop over all the tabs and remove the active class
    tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
      tab.children[2].classList.remove('arrow-up');
    });

    // Set the background of the clicked tab
    //this.classList.add('arrow-up');
    this.children[2].classList.add('arrow-up')
  });
});
```